# Conway's game of life: How to show the next generation

Tags: c++

I am trying to program conway's game of life. I want to print out the next generation with information showing which cells are underpopulated, over populated and juse right.

However, when the user enters that they want to see the next generation, the program outputs the same information.

Does anyone know how I can get the program to output the new information?

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include <array>
#include <cctype>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void print_vector(vector<vector<int>> v, int, int);

int main() {
    int row;
    int col;
    int alive;
    int rowcalc, colcalc;
    string cell = "True";
    int max_value;

    // Input rows & columns
    cout << "Enter number of rows: ";
    cin >> row;
    cout << "Enter number of columns: ";
    cin >> col;

    vector<vector<int>> v1(row, vector<int>(col, 0));
    int count = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < v1[i].size(); j++) {
            v1[i][j] = count;
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }
    print_vector(v1, row, col);
    max_value = row * col;

    while (cell == "True") {
        while (1) {
            cout << "which cell would you like to make alive(0 to stop) ";
            std::cin >> alive;
            if (!std::cin.fail() &&
                (std::cin.peek() == EOF || std::cin.peek() == '\n') &&
                col > 0 && col <= 1000000000) {
                break;
            } else {
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore(256, '\n');
                std::cout << "try inputting something within the bounds. "
                          << std::endl;
            }
        }

        if (alive == 0) cell = "False";
        if (cell == "True") {
            if (alive > 0 && alive <= max_value) {
                rowcalc = floor((alive) / col);
                colcalc = alive % col;
                colcalc = colcalc - 1;
                if (alive % col == 0) {
                    rowcalc = rowcalc - 1;
                    colcalc = colcalc + col;
                }

                if (v1[rowcalc][colcalc] == 0)
                    cout << "already alive. " << endl;
                else
                    v1[rowcalc][colcalc] = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < v1[i].size(); j++)
                        cout << v1[i][j] << setw(3);
                    cout << setw(1);
                    cout << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    string run = "y";
    vector<vector<int>> v2(row, vector<int>(col, 0));
    while (run == "y") {
        int count = 0;
        int count2 = 0;
        vector<int> under;
        vector<int> over;
        vector<int> breeding;
        vector<int> right;

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                count = 0;
                if (i - 1 >= 0 && j - 1 >= 0) {
                    if (v1[i - 1][j - 1] == 0) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                if (i - 1 >= 0) {
                    if (v1[i - 1][j] == 0) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                if (i - 1 >= 0 && j + 1 < col) {
                    if (v1[i - 1][j + 1] == 0) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                if (j + 1 < col) {
                    if (v1[i][j + 1] == 0) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                if (j - 1 >= 0) {
                    if (v1[i][j - 1] == 0) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                if (i + 1 < row) {
                    if (v1[i + 1][j] == 0) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                if (i + 1 < row && j - 1 >= 0) {
                    if (v1[i + 1][j - 1] == 0) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                if (i + 1 < row && j + 1 < col) {
                    if (v1[i + 1][j + 1] == 0) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                count2++;
                if (v1[i][j] == 0) {
                    if (count < 2) {
                        under.push_back(count2);
                    }
                    if (count == 2 or count == 3) {
                        v2[i][j] = 0;
                        right.push_back(count2);
                    }
                    if (count > 3) {
                        over.push_back(count2);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (count == 3) {
                        breeding.push_back(count2);
                        v2[i][j] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < breeding.size(); i++)
            cout << "breedinging" << breeding.at(i) << ' ';
        cout << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < over.size(); i++)
            cout << "overpop" << over.at(i) << ' ';
        cout << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < under.size(); i++)
            cout << "underpop" << under.at(i) << ' ';
        cout << endl;
        cout << "just right";
        for (int i = 0; i < right.size(); i++) {
            cout << right.at(i) << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;

        cout << "do you want to see the next generation?: ";
        cin >> run;

        if (run == "y") {
            count2 = 0;
            count = 0;

            continue;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void print_vector(vector<vector<int>> v, int row, int col) {
    int count;
    count = 1;
    // Input vector's elements
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            v[i][j] = count;
            count++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            cout << v[i][j] << setw(3);
        }
        cout << setw(1);
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is far too much code for this problem. See our page on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and simplify it. Hard-code the starting array, use a simpler rule, find the shortest progra that gives you results different from what you expect. (Along the way you will probably discover the bug yourself, and failing that you will have a much easier puzzle to present to us.)

Comment: as someone that really learned programming from writing life in assembler on a z80 cp/m system, can i say this is way to complicated. a simple game of life is really quite simple. redesign.

Answer (score 2):

I've done some changes to your code:

- First of all, tidy up the output a little bit.
- Also, which I think it was your main question, print the grid after each iteration.
  Alongside this, I have removed `v2`. I understand that you have a starting grid, over which you iterate, modifying it with each iteration. I presume you don't need a copy of the original grid.
- Finally, apply some coding best practices:

  - initialize local variables.
  - move declaration of variables near to its first use.
  - use braces even for one-line blocks.
  - use descriptive variable names: `grid` instead of `v1`, `alive_neighbours` instead of `count`, `current_cell` instead of `count2`...
  - avoid the use of `floor` for integer division.
  - remove some unnecessary headers.
  - simplify some constructs.
  - remove the `using namespace std`.
  - ...

Check [here](https://godbolt.org/z/44s87aTca) if the program is functioning properly now. If not, you will have at least a base point to start debugging it.